# Get the value from database in selecte tag HTML PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL. I successfully get the value from database in **INPUT** type but I can't get the data from database in **SELECT** type:

Here is my sample edit form where **Gender** & **User Type** can't output the value from my database:

[image]

and here is data from the table I created:
[image]

I'm calling the data in my input box by using this code:

```
<?php $userRow['agentFname']; ?>  //$userRow['ROW NAME IN TABLE'];
```

But I can't call the data where In select box, like **Gender:** and **User Type** here is my code of **Select box.**

```
   <select class="form-control" name="aGender" >
           <option selected disabled>*Gender</option>
          <option>Male</option>
          <option>Female</option>

   </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

   <select class="form-control" name="utype" >
           <option selected disabled>*User Type</option>
          <option>Agent</option>
          <option>Team Leader</option>
          <option>Admin</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Something like this `<option value="Male"<?php $userRow['agender'] == 'Male' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Male</option>`

Comment: You need to do it for all `options` in your `select` dropdown

Comment: how about in user type?  I have 3 options:  Agent, Team Leader, Admin

Comment: Let me try this wait.

Comment: Same way `<option value="Agent"<?php $userRow['utype'] == 'Agent' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Agent</option>` and do it similar way for Team and Admin

Comment: Sorry, in the first comment use `...$userRow['aGender']..` as the name is `aGender`

Comment: Sorry still error, But sorry I already fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have my own answer to this
Here how I solved this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="aGender" >
     <?php
       if ($userRow['agentGender'] == 'Male') {

           echo "<option selected>Male</option>";
           echo "<option>Female</option>";

       } else {
           echo "<option selected>Female</option>";
           echo "<option>Male</option>";
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

> @Edmhar has a good answer, but it is hard coded and isn't good if you want to add more genders (transgenders and what not).

What I do is something like this:

```
<?php
$array = array("male", "female", "other");

echo "<select class='form-control' name='aGender' >";
foreach ($array as $gender) {
    if ($gender == $databaseValue) {
       echo "<option selected>$gender</option>";
    } else {
       echo "<option>$gender</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Also, don't use `disabled` on form elements; use `read-only`. It does the same thing as `disabled` visually, but `disabled` does what it says. It blocks the value from being submitted to the database. `read-only` just prevents editing, but doesn't cause form submission problems. User type will follow the same suit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use below conditional code for this issue:

```
<?php if($userRow['aGender'] == 'Male'){
 $selectedMale =  'selected="selected"'
 $selectedFemale =  ''
}else{
  $selectedFemale =  'selected="selected"'
 $selectedMale =  ''
}?>

<select class="form-control" name="aGender" >
           <option selected disabled>*Gender</option>
          <option <?php echo $selectedMale ;?>>Male</option>
          <option <?php echo $selectedFemale;?>>Female</option>

   </select>
```

and same for the another select box.

It will work hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's best to use ternary operator in such a case, combined with options element fetched from db/array. Something like:

```
    <?php $options = Array(1 => "Option 1", 2 => "Option 2")
    <select>
    <?php foreach($options as $key => $opt): ?>
        <option value="<?= $key ?>" ($key == $userRow['value'] ? "selected" : "" )><?= $opt ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```