# how to fetch data from database to select tag in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

found this from [one of the answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117718/get-the-value-from-database-in-selecte-tag-html-php-mysql)

And I would like to ask, is there something wrong with this?
I've var_dump the column course right it displays BSIT.
But I couldn't get if the user is BSIT it goes to the BSCS selected option.

```
<select class="form-control" name="course">
    <?php
        if ($row['course'] == 'BSIT') {

        echo "<option selected>BSIT</option>";
        echo "<option>BSCS</option>";

        } else {
        echo "<option selected>BSCS</option>";
        echo "<option>BSIT</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: where is the "value" attribute?

Comment: @emaillenin what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should declare variable for $row=['course']

```
 <select class="form-control" name="course">
    <?php
        if ($course == 'Bachelor of Science in Information Technology') {

        echo "<option value='Bachelor of Science in Information Technology' selected>Bachelor of Science in Information Technology</option>";
        echo "<option value='Bachelor of Science in Computer Science'>Bachelor of Science in Computer Science</option>";

    } else {
        echo "<option value='Bachelor of Science in Computer Science' selected>Bachelor of Science in Computer Science</option>";
        echo "<option value='Bachelor of Science in Information Technology'>Bachelor of Science in Information Technology</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I've tested it. It's Working

Comment: Wow solved my problem! That's why It always go to the else. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code

```
<?php
// $row['course'] = 'BSCS';
 ?>
<select class="form-control" name="course" >
 <option  <?php if($row['course'] == 'BSIT' ) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?>  >BSIT</option>
<option <?php if($row['course'] == 'BSCS' ) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >BSCS</option>
</select>
```

no need to check condition and change $row['course'] = 'BSIT'; for you test

Comment: Wait what? I dont get it. What was OP's error and how did this even fix it?

Comment: i just update code condition which no need to check and update code that it

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I dont think this is any different from the code of OP.

Comment: i saw that source code working but i was think that why use condition so i just remove if else condition and merge it

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `select` tag here. Also assign value to the option to retrieve it back

```
echo "<select>";
        if ($row['course'] == 'BSIT') {

            echo "<option selected>BSIT</option>";
            echo "<option>BSCS</option>";

        } else {
            echo "<option selected>BSCS</option>";
            echo "<option>BSIT</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

Instead of using echo each time the best practice is to store the content in a variable and echo it after

```
<?php
    $msg="";
//retrieve the $row['course'] from the DB. Fetch the result and store 
        if ($row['course'] == 'BSIT') {

            $msg.= "<option selected>BSIT</option>";
            $msg.= "<option>BSCS</option>";

        } else {
            $msg.= "<option selected>BSCS</option>";
            $msg.= "<option>BSIT</option>";
    }

?>
<select class="form-control" name="course" >
<?php echo $msg;?>
</select>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? He has the select tag in his code.

Comment: edited my code sir, just didn't include it in the first place.

Comment: It is working when it is BSIT and BSCS but i've replaced BSIT and BSCS with Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Bachelor of Science in Information Technology. It's not working

Comment: Check the data retrieved from DB and the if condition. the value  `$row['course']` and the condition should match. **Vote/Accept the answer which solved your problem.**

Comment: i dont know what'ts wrong but i only reads the else statement

Comment: Condition "==" in if is case sensitive, check the case the data in DB and the variable which you are checking

Comment: it is the same with my database, I've var_dump it but it doesn't work with the code

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the content of your curly brackets. Then BSCS will show up as selected when $row['course'] holds 'BSIT' and BSCS for anything else.

Comment: what? switch? why?

Comment: Could you please explain ? I've switched it. Yes, it does work.

Comment: It's how IF statement works. If condtion is true (in your case if $row['course'] holds 'BSIT') it will execute the instructions in your first curly brackets. If not, it will execute the instructions after 'else'.   That's why BSIT was selected in your case - it was in the first set of curly brackets.

Comment: Yea I know how If statement works, but it doesn't read the first statement -_-

Answer (score 0):

I think this will more help to you. Please try this one

```
<select class="form-control" name="course" value="<?php echo $row['course']; ?>">
   <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
   <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
</select>
```

That coure value will be show in dropdown box..

Comment: you're just giving the select tag a value.